# HTML: srcset & sizes, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: html, image, responsive

I try to load my resizes images using HTML srcset and sizes, but the browser still loading only the larger image.

My HTML looks like that:

```
<img
    srcset="/logo-146x30.jpg 146w, /logo-122x25.jpg 122w, /logo-97x20.jpg 97w"
    sizes="(min-width: 651px) 146px, (min-width: 361px) 121px, 97px"
    src="/logo-146x30.jpg"
    alt="alt text"
/>
```

I have also try to opposite media queries like:

```
<img
    srcset="/logo-146x30.jpg 146w, /logo-122x25.jpg 122w, /logo-97x20.jpg 97w"
    sizes="(max-width: 360px) 97px, (max-width: 650px) 121px, 146px"
    src="/logo-146x30.jpg"
    alt="alt text"
/>
```

In both cases, I always get the image `/logo-146x30.jpg`.

I have tried re-load the browser in scaled downsize, but either way, the only loaded image is the `/logo-146x30.jpg`.

Also the viewport meta is like that:

```
<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no"
>
```

Do you see anything wrong with what I have done so far?

Answer (score -1):

Instead using srcset and sizes, use CSS media queries. This is from the top of my mind, but try somenthing like (this is based on your first image):

HTML:

```
<div class="image" />
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 651px) {
  .image {
    background-image: url(/logo-146x30.jpg);
  }    
}

@media screen and (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 650px) {
  .image {
    background-image: url(/logo-122x25.jpg);
  }
}
```

Remember to use min-width and max-width in @media so it won't be overriden.
Try using min-width and max-width in your solution also.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Second, it is not me that downvoted you :) Finally, the solution you suggest is not applicable to my case. I need to have a read <img> tag, and not write the image using CSS. :)